# How can I switch between users when using Windows 10 Picture Passwords?

Tags: windows-10, password-management

We have multiple Windows 10 user accounts with picture passwords on a desktop PC.

When signing my account in, if a different user was signed in previously, the sign-in screen will default to their picture. Switching to my own picture appears to be a pain - the only way I have found to do it is switch to a text password, then switch users, then switch back to the picture password. Ugh!

Is there an easier way to switch between users' picture passwords?

Comment: You might have to accept that Microsoft did not design this option to work with multiple users using multiple pictures and all users using the picture password.

Comment: Good point - but surely this is an oversight. I hit this issue within 20 minutes of the upgrade. I'll bet that it's 'patched' pretty soon.

Comment: I've been looking to answer this, but there seems no updates after august. Do you still have this issue?

Comment: @Terry Yes. This is still an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Below the user account name, you have two links: one for accessing other sign-in options for the same user account and one for switching the user account. Click or tap “Switch user” and then a list is shown with all the user accounts that exist on your Windows 10 computer or device. For screen shots check here: [How to switch between user accounts in Windows 10](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-switch-between-user-accounts-windows-10).